# Is my GParted resize stuck?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning, live-usb, gparted

I'm currently doing a GParted resize on my Windows partition so that I can create a second partition on which to install Ubuntu. The drive is a 512GB NVMe SSD.

GParted's shrink progress bar hasn't moved for quite a while; the process has been running for about 2 hours and it hasn't moved for about 30 minutes. It seems to still be on the *Relocating needed data* stage, which I acknowledge could take a while because the drive is quite full, but it seems to be taking a while on 39.63%.

I'm running GParted off an Ubuntu 16.04 Live USB.

This is my GParted operations window:

[image]

What should I do? Is there any way to get a more in-depth progress report which may indicate whether GParted has frozen or not?

#### Edit

I figured out how to install `iotop`, so I can now see that `ntfsresize` appears to be performing IO, which is reassuring. I'll just be patient.

[image]

Comment: Give GParted some more time to finish before you give up. You don't want to do anything that could cause you to lose the data that is stored in the partition.

Comment: @karel I've seen other answers saying that, but can it really take this long on 0.01%? Or does the percentage only update occasionally?

Comment: It has been my experience that the progress bar is often eccentric about the way it advances and extremely inaccurate. In particular it does nothing for a long time and then abruptly jumps to the end when it finishes.

Comment: @karel Alright then, I'll give it longer. Thanks for your speedy reply.

Comment: it is best to use windows to resize windows partitions. However, since you started with gparted, let it continue. Are you sure there is enough room to reduce the amount you wanted to? Is Fast Startup disabled in windows?

Comment: @ravery There is enough space, yes. Fast Startup and Hibernate are disabled.

Comment: I would recommend that you 1. Repair the file system with Windows; 2. Use Windows to shrink the partition (the Windows partition), and leave the space intended for Ubuntu as unallocated drive space; 3. Boot into a live Ubuntu system; 4. Use gparted to create partitions (one root partition and one swap partition); 5. Start the installer and install Ubuntu; 6. Select 'Something else' at the partitioning window and use the partitions that you created with gparted.

Comment: @sudodus Shrinking with Windows certainly seems like a better idea in hindsight. First step is to repair the disk, which I'll do overnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was stuck. Even after leaving it for about 17 hours, there was no progress update or any other change, despite `ntfsresize` working at almost 100% IO according to `iotop`. Force Cancel didn't even work - I had to `kill`.

Upon rebooting, Windows actually booted fine (much to my surprise) and my files appear to be intact, but `chkdsk` flags up a lot of errors:

```
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 2B0
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 771
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 809
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 826
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 835
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment AC8
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment BD6
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 14E1
is corrupt.
The total allocated size in attribute record (80, "")
of file 130000000018F5 is incorrect.
Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code 80 in file 18F5.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 22FB2
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 22FBF
is corrupt.
Attribute record (80, "") from file record segment 22FD0
... and many more
```